# obtain the max y-value of a histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for suggestions on how to calculate the maximum y-value of a histogram.

```
#simple histogram. how can I obtain the maximum value of, say, x and y?

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
hdata = randn(500)
x = plt.hist(hdata)
y = plt.hist(hdata, bins=40)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`hist` returns a tuple that contains the histogram bin locations and y values. Try this:

```
y, x, _ = plt.hist(hdata)

print x.max()
print y.max()
```

Note that `len(y) = len(x) - 1`.

Comment: yeah, usually edits to code are hard to get accepted. I figured that with 5 upvotes, I had justification (:

Comment: do you know how to get label of x axis where y.max() is ?

Answer (score 4):

In case you also want to know the corresponding x coordinate for the beginning of that interval, following @tiago's suggestion you can add:

```
 x[np.where(y == y.max())]
```

Comment: Or use y.argmax()