# Python matplotlib histogram: edit x-axis based on maximum frequency in bin

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, axis

I am trying to make a series of histograms by looping through a series of arrays containing values. For each array my script is producing a separate histogram. Using the default settings, this results in histograms in which the bar with the highest frequency touches the top of the graph ([this is what it looks like now)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVZMc.png). I would like there to be some space: [this is what I want it to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9n3V.png)

My question is: how do I make the maximum value of the y-axis dependent of the maximum frequency occurring in my bins? I want the y-axis to be slightly longer than my longest bar.

I cannot do this by setting the value like so:

```
plt.axis([100, 350, 0, 5])  #[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
```

or

```
matplotlib.pyplot.ylim(0,5)
```

because I am plotting a series of histograms, and the max frequencies strongly vary.

My code now looks something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for LIST in LISTS:
    plt.figure()
    plt.hist(LIST)
    plt.title('Title')
    plt.xlabel("x-axis [unit]")
    plt.ylabel("Frequency")
    plt.savefig('figures/'LIST.png')
```

How do I define the y-axis to run from 0 to 1.1 * (the max frequency in 1 bin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you are hoping to achieve?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random as nprnd
import numpy as np

LISTS = []

#Generate data
for _ in range(3):
    LISTS.append(nprnd.randint(100, size=100))

#Find the maximum y value of every data set
maxYs = [i[0].max() for i in map(plt.hist,LISTS)]
print "maxYs:", maxYs

#Find the largest y 
maxY = np.max(maxYs)
print "maxY:",maxY

for LIST in LISTS:
    plt.figure()
    #Set that as the ylim
    plt.ylim(0,maxY)
    plt.hist(LIST)
    plt.title('Title')
    plt.xlabel("x-axis [unit]")
    plt.ylabel("Frequency")
    #Got rid of the safe function
plt.show()
```

Produces the graphs with the largest y limit the same as maxY. Also some debug output:

```
maxYs: [16.0, 13.0, 13.0]
maxY: 16.0
```

The function `plt.hist()` returns a tuple with the `x, y` data set. So you can call `y.max()` to get the maximum for each set. [Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15558796/5782727)

Comment: Not entirely, but it does solve my problem. I was looking for the term maxY. All I have to do now is multiply maxY by 1.1 in order for the Y-axis to be 10% longer than my maximum Y-value. Thank you!