# How do I plot a histogram where the maximum y-value is one?

Tags: python, histogram, normalization

I have the following histogram:

[image]

The blue columns are the data while the red line is the theoretical line. I generated this by first plotting the histogram, and then scaling the theoretical curve (which has a maximum of 1) to the approximate value of the peak of the histogram. I want to avoid this manual scaling by making the histogram have a peak value of 1 as well. How do I do this with Python?

[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558136/obtain-the-max-y-value-of-a-histogram) provides a way to get the peak value (122 in my case) but I can't figure out how to use that to scale the histogram. It seems like once I invoke the hist command it will create the current histogram, which makes sense since that's what histograms are - the columns shouldn't take fractional values. In other words I need a different approach. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `plt.hist` again but with `weights` parameter that specifies scaling factors:

```
plt.hist(hdata, bins=40, weights=[1/y.max()]*x_len)
```